# Is counter right datatype to monitor revenue over time in Prometheus?

Tags: histogram, prometheus, counter, monitoring, observability

I am trying to understand which datatype is right choice to monitor revenue metric in Prometheus.

Answer (score 1):

A [Gauge](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge) is appropriate because your revenue value (per period of time) may increase|decrease and you can set a Gauge to any float value.

You can then use `sum_over_time` (e.g. a month) to aggregate the (e.g. daily) revenue represented by the Gauge measurements.

The only unit measure alternative is a [Counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter) but Counter values may only increase in value.

Prometheus [Metric Types](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/)